# ColdFusion - Output Grouping From a Query

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, cfquery, cfloop

I have a great question that is probably bone-head simple.  I have the following query:

```
<cfquery name="getempareview" dbtype="query">
  SELECT firstname,lastname,deptname,supcode
  FROM getreviews
  WHERE supcode IN (#preserveSingleQuotes(setsupcode)#)
</cfquery>
```

What I need to do is output so that the supcode has the other data under it in a list.  So, if I have 100 rows of data and the supcode is the same on 25 of the records, just have the following:

supcode
     firstname lastname - deptname (all 25 records would be listed out here)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not related to your question, but using a cfqueryparam tag with the list attribute set to yes is more reliable than using PreserveSingleQuotes.

Comment: Related to your question, in order for @TRose's correct answer to give you the desired results, you have to add an order by clause to your query.

Comment: This is a query of query. Does it need to be? You might be able to get all of your information in a single query. Are you running a base query to get a list of `setsupcode`s? That's a lot of extra work on your database and your network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested outputs. Try this.

```
<cfoutput query="YourQueryName" group="SupCode">
<h2>#SupCode#</h2>
<cfoutput>
#FirstName# #LastName# <br/>
</cfoutput>

</cfoutput>
```

Comment: on the right path, but need to get everyone under a supcode grouped together.  Please see this url and many thanks for your assistance:  https://okcic.net/sites/quarterlyeval-current/test-query.cfm

Answer (score 1):

You need to use nested and grouped output. And add an `ORDER BY` to your query.

```
<cfset setsupcode = "1,3,5">

<cfquery name="getempareview" dbtype="query">
  SELECT firstname,lastname,deptname,supcode
  FROM getreviews
  WHERE supcode IN (<cfqueryparam value="#setsupcode#" cfsqltype="numeric" list="yes">)
  ORDER BY supcode, deptname, lastname, firstname
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query="getempareview" group="supcode">
    <h2>#supcode#</h2>
    <cfoutput group="deptname">
        #firstname# #lastname# (#deptname#) <br>
    </cfoutput>
</cfoutput>
```

https://trycf.com/gist/763ede5485b0978504250f7f5baf9deb/acf11?theme=solarized_dark

Also, since this is apparently a Query of Query, you may be able to better organize your data in your initial query, rather than having to come back to reprocess the data.